# What are the advantages of sexual reproduction over asexual reproduction?

Tags: genetics, reproduction, natural-selection, sexual-reproduction, asexual-reproduction

What are the advantages of sexual reproduction over asexual reproduction?

How does variation influence ecological and evolutionary success?

Comment: The question is unclear. You might want to rephrase. As you say, sexual reproduction is good for life because it's a method of reproduction, which allows for survival, which life requires by definition. But that's just tautological. Do you mean to ask what the benefits of sexual reproduction are over asexual methods for an organism in an ecological/evolutionary context? Or would you like to know the biological, cellular and molecular mechanisms which occur exclusively in sexually-reproducing species that allow for variation? Please clarify.

Comment: I meant to know the benefits of sexual reproduction over asexual reproduction

Comment: *Genetic* variation -- a variation in alleles to enable organisms to avoid passing on mutations/traits that reduce fitness and possibly create new combinations of alleles that lead to traits that actually increase fitness. You might also want to take a look at population genetics and microevolution to see how this plays out at a larger scale.

Comment: Please consider using a search engine for these kinds of questions. This question has been addressed nauseatingly often. PS: The main advantage of sexual reproduction is the introduction of a LOT of genetic variation which is not achieved through budding/regeneration/fragmentation (asexual reproduction). Variation is fundamental to evolution and as such has a protective, prophylactic effect against parasites and disease. Unique offspring are produced each time. The downside is that it's more energy-costly, takes a lot of time, requires two organisms (parents) and produces fewer offspring.

Comment: @SPr I was just wondering what else was it good for rather than the points you mentioned. The points you mentioned are addressed often to this question. I was wondering if there were any other reason. All the websites I entered , ultimately only mentioned that it's good for production of complex organisms, makes lot of variation which helps both adapt and speciate. Not anything else.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the core advantage. Sexual reproduction is *not* "good for production of complex organisms" - this is a misunderstanding. It's an effective strategy to introduce genetic variation between individuals of a species. It occurs in many simple organisms too. Variation is very, very important in evolution. A lineage with steadily high levels of variation between successive generations can escape diseases, be resistant to parasites, is protected from major genetic mutation events, and has the additional benefits of sexual selection. These all lower the chances of extinction!

Comment: One question at a time please.